# Test for whether method decreases the metric or not

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

we have created a software for a given task. What we wanted to achieve is 1) to speed up the process 2) without lowering the quality of the work. Now I would like to run a test to see if 2) stands. My question is how should I go about this?

First I thought I should do a one-tailed paired t test. If I'm correct, for one-tailed t tests generally

- the alternative hypothesis is that the second group is significantly higher (or lower) than the first group, and
- the null hypothesis is that the second group is not higher (lower) than the first group, i.e. lower (higher) or equal.

Now my problem is, that in this test the null hypothesis would be accepted when the two datasets are similar (difference is ~0), although in our case that could also be rejected (so the alternate hypothesis can be accepted).
So my question would be, how should I define the test in order to test for the second method "not being worse" than the first? I thought, that I should define the inverse problem and try to prove the null hypothesis, but I learnt that [one should never try to prove the null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea) (in the tea tasting example, if the lady guesses 3 out of 4 correctly, the p value is higher than 5%, but that doesn't mean that we disproved the lady's powers, we just can't be sure enough to accept it).

Is a t test a good choice in this situation? Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to CV. You are looking for 'non-inferiority', have a search on the site for that.

Comment: What is your measure of "quality of the work" ?

Comment: @PBulls thanks for the tip! I found some discussions where non-inferiority is defined as not being worse than a given value. This basically means to run a t-test with setting $\mu$. to that threshold value. Actually I thought about the same idea, I just didn't like the fact that there will be another parameter for "acceptable mistakes". But if there's no better solution, then be it.

Comment: @CaroZ it is an IoU score compared to a reference image annotation, which will be a value between 0 (meaning completely different annotations) and 1 (identical annotations).

Comment: Is it completely interger or are there for example 0.75 ?

Comment: @CaroZ It's continuous, it can be any value between 0 and 1.